# CSS clearfix/float issue? Fade in content different heights not pushing content down

Tags: jquery, css, absolute, clearfix

I have content that is going to be different heights that I have fading into a div. How do I have it push the content that is below and not cover it up? I believe it is a CSS issue? A clearfix? I haven't been able to fix it, I'm not sure it the clear fix should go on the wrapper of the fading content or the content below that needs pushed??

http://jsfiddle.net/7hqyq/186/

Any advice or a better way to code this would be appreciated.

All of my code is below:
jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#secondary a').on('click',function(){
        $('#secondary a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

function fader(i) {
    $('.panel').stop().fadeTo(500, 0).eq(!i ? i :$(this).index()).fadeTo(500, 1); }
    $("li").on("click", fader);
});  // end document ready
```

CSS:

```
#secondary { 
    padding:4% 0 3% 0; 
    list-style-type:none;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
}
#secondary a {
    float:left;
    padding: .5% 2%;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#1F4B80;
}
#secondary a:hover, #secondary a.active {
    background-color:#1F4B80;
    color:#FFF;
}


#details {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    min-height:300px;
    background:#999;
    border:1px solid red;

}
#details .panel {
    position:absolute;
    width:82.5%;
    padding: 3% 8%;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:none;
    border:1px solid blue;
    background:#999;
}


#links {
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding: 4% 8%;
    overflow:auto;
    width: 84%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#links div {
    width:225px;
    height:170px;
    margin:1%;
    padding-bottom:2%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:#1F4B80;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
<ul id="secondary">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Community Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Online Editions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Member Benefits</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Process</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Maps</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">How to Get Started</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<div id="details">
    <div class="panel"><h2>About Member Organizations</h2></div>
    <div class="panel"><h2>Services</h2></div>
    <div class="panel"><h2>Community Profile</h2></div>
    <div class="panel"><h2>Online Editions</h2></div>
    <div class="panel"><h2>Member Benefits</h2></div>
    <div class="panel"><h2>Process</h2></div>
    <div class="panel"><h2>Maps</h2></div>
    <div class="panel"><h2>How to Get Started</h2></div>
</div>

<div id="links">
    <div><a>Community Profile Samples</a></div>
    <div><a>Visitor Guide Samples</a></div>
    <div><a>Map Samples</a></div>
    <div><a>Association Samples</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don’t see how that fiddle is supposed to be showing the issue.

Comment: Anyhow, when you position an element absolutely, you are taking it out of normal flow, so it doesn’t influence the following elements any more – looks like that is what you’re doing with your `.panel` elements.

Comment: Fiddle with code. http://jsfiddle.net/7hqyq/186/

Comment: I'd restructure to use a more conventional accordion. Those absolutely-positioned containers will be a perpetual headache.

Comment: The absolute position is needed to make the fade work.

Comment: I've read and re-read, still not clear the specific issue, nor the specific requirement. Perhaps an illustration would help?

Comment: I am restricted from adding images here yet.... My issue is that when the text overflows ( like if you click "Map" in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7hqyq/186/) it covers up the blue boxes and does not push the content. I think I need #details (the red bordered box) to grow with the .panels (the blue bordered box)?? .panels has a position:absolute making it out of the flow...... idk